# Can a Lindlar catalyst reduce aldehydes, nitriles, and carbonitriles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, amines, organic-reduction, nitriles

The major product obtained in the following reaction is:

[image]

Question source: [JEE Main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination#JEE_Main) 2019

The molecule shown as product is the official answer given by JEE from the given options.

I have written the possible intermediate molecule formed by reagents. On Google I have obtained information in [this PDF document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.luriechildrens.org/contentassets/d24236bbdf2446db881001b0be4bfe3e/reducing-agents.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiUmNfWzKDyAhU7wzgGHeMTAZgQFnoECB0QAg&usg=AOvVaw0Usy_7OPasdnVQlGovExuu&cshid=1628398911478) (page 3) that a [Lindlar catalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindlar_catalyst) is poisoned, so that it cannot reduce an aldehyde. Also there is no information of a Lindlar catalyst being used as the reducing agent for nitriles and carbonitriles.

So, is the answer by JEE incorrect or am I missing something?

Comment: Note: $\ce{Pd/C}$ is not similar to $\ce{Pd/BaSO4}$ or $\ce{Pd/CaCO3}$. So the reagent in your question isn't Lindlar's catalyst in the first place. It behaves like normal $\ce{Pd/H2}$ as far as I've learnt.

Comment: From MasterOrganicChemistry Reagent Guide - Pd/C reduces alkene, alkyne, nitro, cyanide, C=N, azide - and probably most other reducible groups too.

Comment: From *Organic Chemistry for JEE Advanced by KS Verma, Cengage publications* - It reduces all of the above but they haven't mentioned alkyne and C=N. Most likely missed mentioning those two.

Comment: Re *"carbonitriles"*: Just *"[nitriles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrile)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Essentially they are the same, but in some nomenclature rules, carbonitrile is used instead of nitrile: https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_566.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just a silly mistake. As [TRC told](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155693/can-lindlar-catalyst-reduce-aldehyde-nitrile-and-carbonitrile#comment319615_155693), $\ce{Pd/C}$ is not a Lindlar catalyst and it behaves as a normal $\ce{Pd/H2}$. Refer to [the link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium_on_carbon) for more information.